# Change the font-size in grid system

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using the grid system to show 7 little images with a number next to each one of the images and it should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQYve.jpg). In this first example i didn't use the grid system but it was much more complicated and it took me 60 - 120 minutes to do it and using the grid system i took less than 10 minutes BUT i can't resize the font. Have a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8KlA.jpg)

I tried overwriting any possible font-size attribute, and i also tried giving more classes to the divs and changing the font-size.

NOTE: I could easily change the font-family though.

```html
 <div class="container" style="float: left; font-family: 'Germania One', cursive;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <img src="forca.png" alt=""> 2
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="destreza.png" alt=""> 3
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="agilidade.png" alt=""> 2
          </div>
          <div class="col">
             <img src="inteligencia.png" alt=""> 8
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="resistencia.png" alt=""> 4
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="fe.png" alt=""> 2
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="carisma.png" alt=""> 4
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm unable to duplicate your issue. Adding font-size property to your attached html does in fact change the font size. Try inspecting the numbers in Chrome devtools -- what is setting the font size (and overriding your setting)?

Comment: And where is your CSS which should change the font-size ? Maybe your selector is wrong.

Comment: Thank you guys! I got it. There was a style overwriting the other. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div class="container" style="float: left; font-family: 'Germania One', cursive;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <img src="forca.png" alt=""> 
            <p style="font-size:2em">2</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="destreza.png" alt=""> 
            <p style="font-size:2em">3</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="agilidade.png" alt=""> 
            <p style="font-size:2em">2</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
             <img src="inteligencia.png" alt=""> 
            <p style="font-size:2em">8</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="resistencia.png" alt=""> 
            <p style="font-size:2em">4</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="fe.png" alt=""> 
            <p style="font-size:2em">2</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="carisma.png" alt=""> 
            <p style="font-size:2em">4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```